# Solr 7.5 parsing phrase query wrong

Tags: parsing, solr, special-characters, whitespace, solr-query-syntax

Here is the query our code produces when searching for a phone number.

```
(DOC_DTG:[2010-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z] OR (*:* NOT DOC_DTG:[* TO *])) AND "(972) 492 - 5495"
```

When i run it in the solr ui the area code shows up twice in the parsed query.  The parsed query look like this:

```
+(DOC_DTG:[1262304000000 TO 253402300799000] (*:* -DOC_DTG:[-9223372036854775808 TO 9223372036854775807])) +DOC_TEXT:"(972 (972)) 492 - 5495
```

We're using the LuceneQParser:

```
"QParser":"LuceneQParser"
```

Why does the area code show up twice?

I tried escaping the parenthesis and the space still the same outcome. When I remove the parenthesis everything is fine. Any help would be great.

Comment: What analysers do you use for the DOC_TEXT field in your schema.xml?

Comment: We use indexer and query as our analyzer.